# How to restrict Text widget input to certain characters with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Text widget (`my_text`) in my program that should only accept certain characters. If the user enters a character that isn't defined in a dictionary (`ACCEPTED`), the program should either ignore the input entirely or, at the very least, remove the character right after it's been entered. Otherwise, the program should output the corresponding value into `my_text2`.

I'm doing my best to also ensure that my program accounts for text entered *before* the end of the text content. For example, say a user goes back and inserts text in the middle of a sentence; this program should still function as expected. This is an example of the logic I'm working with:

```py
import tkinter as tk


# For this example, I'm converting the output from
# a QWERTY keyboard to the output of a Dvorak keyboard.
ACCEPTED = {
    "q": "'",
    "w": ",",
    "e": ".",
    "r": "p",
    "t": "y",
    "y": "f",
    # ...
}


def handle_input(s):
    my_text2.configure(state = tk.NORMAL)

    if s.char in set(ACCEPTED):
        my_text2.insert(
            my_text.index(tk.INSERT),
            ACCEPTED[s.char]
        )

    elif s.keysym.lower() in {"backspace", "delete"}:
        my_text2.delete(
            my_text.index(tk.INSERT)
            + "-1c" * (s.keysym.lower() == "backspace")
        )

    # This is the part I'm missing.
    else:
        pass

    my_text2.configure(state = tk.DISABLED)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("648x163+10+10")

my_text = tk.Text(
    root,
    width = 40,
    height = 10,
)
my_text.bind("<Key>", handle_input)

my_text2 = tk.Text(
    root,
    width = 40,
    height = 10,
    state = tk.DISABLED,
)

my_text.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
my_text2.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

**These two Text widgets must remain synced for my program to function properly.**

So far, I've tried `my_text.delete(tk.INSERT)`, `my_text.delete(tk.CURRENT)`, and a `"-1c"` variant of both. I'm still fairly new to Tkinter, so I'm not sure what's going on. It looks to me like the text isn't actually entered into `my_text` until after `handle_input()` runs, meaning that there won't be anything to delete. When I enter a character that isn't defined in `ACCEPTED`, it still shows up in `my_text`, which desyncs the two Text widgets.

Everywhere where I've found a similar issue, the problem at hand doesn't account for text before `tk.END`, but I'm trying to match up these two Text widgets perfectly, so `tk.END` won't work for me.

Comment: If you want to stop `tkinter` from processing the key just use: `return "break"`. That will tell tkinter to ignore the event.

Comment: @TheLizzard If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it. This solves my problem; thanks!

Comment: Ok I will write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `"break"` from a function that is called from an event, will stop the event. That means that `tkinter`'s widget will never get the event.